# DataTables warning: Requested unknown parameter(6) for row (0)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've looked at a few SO questions regarding this error, but none of the answers fixed my problem.

HTML

```
<div id="assign_time_invoice_dialog" title="Select Time" class='assign_time_invoice dialog' style="display:none">
    <table id="time_dt" class="display dt_selectable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Rate</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Length</th>
                <th>WIP</th>
                <th>Job</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$( "#assign_time_invoice_dialog" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:600,
      width:800,
      modal: true,
      open: function( event, ui ) {
            var data = {client_id:invoice_client_id};
            if (!dataTableCust) {
                dataTableCust = $('#time_dt').DataTable( {
                    'ajax': {
                        'url': 'ajax_time_dt.php',
                        'data': data
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        {"data": "timetrack_description"},
                        {"data": "timetrack_user_rate"},
                        {"data": "timetrack_start"},
                        {"data": "timetrack_length"},
                        {"data": "wip_description"},
                        {"data": "job_description"}
                    ],
                    "columnDefs": [
                        {
                            "targets": [6],
                            "visible": false,
                            "searchable": false,
                        }
                    ],
                    "iDisplayLength": 100,
                    "scrollX": true,
                    "scrollY":        "410px",
                    "scrollCollapse": true,
                    "pagingType": "simple",
                    "oLanguage": {
                      "sSearch": "Search for time:"
                    },
                } );
            }
      },
      buttons : button_options
    });
```

JSON response

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "DT_RowId":"1",
         "timetrack_description":"Wednesday timetrack",
         "timetrack_user_rate":"100.00",
         "timetrack_start":"24\/06\/2015",
         "timetrack_length":"10:42",
         "wip_description":"Accounts",
         "job_description":"fifth test job"
      },
      {  
         "DT_RowId":"42",
         "timetrack_description":"New one",
         "timetrack_user_rate":"80.00",
         "timetrack_start":"30\/06\/2015",
         "timetrack_length":"01:30",
         "wip_description":"iXBRL",
         "job_description":"None"
      }
   ]
}
```

Using this code I get the error posted in the title. After clicking OK on the alert the DataTable is populated with the data as it should. Inspecting the rows show the correct ID assigned to each row also. So why am I seeing the error?

If I change `"targets"` from '6' to '5' then I no longer see the error, but I also no longer see the last 'Job' column in the table.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hiding the 7th column by using columndefs on target[6] and visible:none 
(https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs)

If you change it to 5 you're hiding the 6th column ( {"data": "job_description"} )

Another problem seems to be that your header table has less columns than the data itself.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that, it was the columnDefs. Thanks!